# mail-listener2: cannot get string 'address' from object

Tags: node.js

I'm using mail-listener2 to get emails from my gmail account.

i'm trying to get a string 'address' from 'mail.to' object, but i got "undefined". Can someone help me?

**log:**

```
imapConnected
email: emailt.ost.ea.m.a.c.c.o@gmail.com
mail.to: [{"address":"emailt.ost.ea.m.a.c.c.o@gmail.com","name":""}]
mail.to typeof: object
MessageTo: undefined
```

**code:**

```
const MailListener = require("mail-listener2");
const mailListener = new MailListener({
    username: "*",
    password: "*",
    host: "imap.gmail.com",
    port: 993,
    tls: true,
    connTimeout: 10000,
    authTimeout: 5000, 
    mailbox: "INBOX",
    searchFilter: ["UNSEEN"],
    markSeen: false,
    fetchUnreadOnStart: true
});

mailListener.start();
mailListener.on("server:connected", function(){
    console.log("imapConnected");
}); 
getCodeFromEmail('', 0, 10000, "emailt.ost.ea.m.a.c.c.o@gmail.com", function(code){
    console.log(code);
});
function getCodeFromEmail(string, offset, length, email, callback) {
    var callback = function(mail) {
        console.log("email: " + email);
        console.log("mail.to: " + JSON.stringify(mail.to));
        console.log("mail.to typeof: " + typeof mail.to)
        if(mail.to.address == email) {
            callback(mail.html.substr(mail.html.lastIndexOf(string) + offset, length));
            mailListener.removeListener('mail', callback);
        } else console.log("MessageTo: " + mail.to.address)
    };
    mailListener.on('mail', callback);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bracket:

```
mail.to: [{"address":"emailt.ost.ea.m.a.c.c.o@gmail.com","name":""}]
         ^
```

suggest that the `mail.to` is an array and not a object. So would need something like:

```
mail.to[0].address
```

Comment: Side note: `typeof [1, 2]` will also return "object"

Comment: I don't know to explain this, your suggest works fine, but when im starting to if(mail.to[0].address == email) i get error: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. try my code with your suggest

Comment: I looked a bit around, I think that the `to` field may to be present always

Comment: so how i can get `to`?

Comment: I mean the email does not have a `to` header/information (its possible)
EDIT: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177713/how-did-i-get-this-email-without-a-to-field

Comment: yes, but i can't `mail.header.delivered-to` cause of `-`

Comment: For mail.header.delivered-to you can do `mail.header["delivered-to"]`